# Error importing a existing project into wakanda studio

Tags: wakanda

I tried to import a working project into my workspace in wakanda studio 1.1.3 it show me the following error

> web:src:app:home:home.component.ts doesn't exist

It works in a windows machine if i open the same project but it doesn't works on my mac.

I tried to reinstall the entire application again but still getting the same error, Is anyone having this kind of issue.

Comment: have you reinstalled your node_modules?

Comment: yes i am getting the same error even after that, actually the wakanda studio show not responding after the project is being opened

Comment: Could be because the `home.component.ts` file was open in the studio. When you open the solution on your Mac, it is trying to open again the file in the studio but could not find it at the same location.

Comment: What do you mean by It doesn't work ? The solution is not open in the studio ? you don't see your files in the solution explorer ? You can't load the solution to the server ?

Comment: @Yann you are correct i changed the location of the project and it works fine

Comment: @skid Great, I'm writing the same text as an answer to get more visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `home.component.ts` file was open in the studio when you close your solution. The studio keeps track of all `currently` open files and reopen them next time.

When you move the solution to your Mac, the studio tries to re-open the files; could not find some at the same location and returns an error.

You can safely ignore this error. Next time, you close your solution, the studio will save the new `currently` open file list.